# Admin Toolbar not working

Tags: 8

I downloaded the [Admin_toolbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar) module, installed and enabled it with Drush (`drush en admin_toolbar -y`).

If I look in admin, it's enabled. But it's not working; it's not hovering.

*Notes:*

- I have a Git workflow. But for now I just installed it locally. I had some issues with the `$config_directories`. For the configuration files. Could this may have to do with this? Now I returned to default settings in settings.php and in `admin/reports/status` I get no errors.
- I installed with Acquia Dev Desktop and have Mac OSX. Shall I trie de-install and install again maybe?

Comment: Just installed it (via drush like you) and the hovering works fine, only on the white menu (content, structure, appearance, etc.) and only when it's set to a horizontal position. Anything particular about your system?

Comment: no nothing particular. I have a Git workflow. But for now I just installed it locally. I had some issues with the `$config_directories`. For the configuration files. Could this may have to do with this? Now I returned to default settings in settings.php and in `admin/reports/status` I get no errors.

Comment: Hmmm... Difficult to say something with so little info. Could you post your http://supportdetails.com/ ?

Comment: I installed with Acquia Dev Desktop and have Mac OSX. Shall I trie de-install and install again maybe?

Comment: Sure, you can always try that :-)  I use a linuxServer/windows+firefox environment. I can try with the Acquia Dev Desktop, let me know after you try the de-re installation.

Answer (score 1):

I used `drush cache-rebuild` and now it works!

Comment: Definitive solution to any problems (working 99.99% of times): rebuild the cache. :D